# Как подключить шрифты с файла .ttf на страничку? (css)

Tags: html, css, шрифты

подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить на страничку шрифты с файла .ttf или .eot

И как их затем использовать?

Пробовал через @font-face, но не вышло (Возможно что-то прописал нет так).

[image: Пробовал так подключать, не вышло]

[image: Для текста]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагмент кода не велик, зачем городить скриншоты?

По-существу: атрибут src надо указать один раз, и пары url() format() передать ему через запятую, как то-то так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cricket Light";
  src: url("fonts/eot/Cricket Light.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("fonts/ttf/AGRevueCyr Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Это по крайней мере должно работать, если у вас в папке, где лежит css-файл, есть папка fonts, а в ней также есть папки eot и ttf, соответственно и в них помещены указанные шрифты.

Только я бы не советовал вам в шрифт с font-family: "Cricket Light" помещать РАЗНЫЕ шрифты в разных форматах. Правильнее  было бы для ttf шрифта написать отдельный @font-face.